# Change resolution with ChangeDisplaySettings while desktop is extended causes black screen

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I use this function to change resolution:

ChangeResolution(NULL,1440, 900);

```
bool ChangeResolution(WCHAR *sDeviceName, int iNewW, int iNewH)
{
    DEVMODE oDEVMODE = { 0 };
    oDEVMODE.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    EnumDisplaySettings(sDeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &oDEVMODE);

    oDEVMODE.dmPelsWidth = iNewW;
    oDEVMODE.dmPelsHeight = iNewH;
    bool bUpdateReg = true;
    LONG lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&oDEVMODE, CDS_TEST | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY);
    if (lRet != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&oDEVMODE, CDS_TEST);
        bUpdateReg = false;
    }
    if (lRet == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&oDEVMODE, bUpdateReg?CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY : 0);

    return lRet == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

This works well.

Problem happens when I desktop is extended (pressing the Windows key + P and choosing "extend"). Then while desktop is extended (to non psychical display), after using my ChangeResolution the screen become black as soon as my function calls ChangeDisplaySettings(&oDEVMODE, bUpdateReg?CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY : 0);

The way to get the screen back is to press Windows Key+P again and then press Enter.

(Since screen is black you do not really see what you do).

It becomes black no matter which new resolution i set.

If I try to change resolution while in extended mode but from Control Panel that is works great so the problem is with my function.

I think this happens since when i change resolution for the default screen (NULL), i also need to change something for the virtual screen - but i am not sure.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still facing this problem?